# Rails 5 - download a paperclip attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In the app I am building to learn RoR, I want to automatically download an attached pdf. Attached with Paperclip. Then to get the pdf properties using pdfinfo.

In my `annotation.rb` model I attach using

```
has_attached_file :file,
    styles: { large: "600x600>", medium: "500x500>", thumb: "150x150#" },
    default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

In my AnnotationsController

```
    require 'pdfinfo'
    pdfinfo = Pdfinfo.new('@annotation.file.path')
    page_count = pdfinfo.page_count
```

this throws an error

> Pdfinfo::CommandFailed in AnnotationsController#pdf pdfinfo -f 0 -l -1
>   -enc UTF-8 @annotation.file.path

What does this error mean and how can I get the file to be read? I learned about downloading using send_file, but have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a literal string to the new method. You need to remove the quotes.

```
require 'pdfinfo'
pdfinfo = Pdfinfo.new(@annotation.file.path)
page_count = pdfinfo.page_count
```